# Converting existing Java EE project's encoding form ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am working at a Java EE (JSF) project which is derived from an older one. Such old project has been developed using ISO-8859-1 for encoding everything. I would like to use UTF-8 in the new project but the problem is that obviously if I just set eclipse to use UTF-8 instead of Cp1252, the old source files get "mojibaked". Do you know how could I fix this and use UTF-8 everywhere?

Thanks a lot! Bye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `iconv` to convert all files, commit and then change Eclipse project settings.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering! The best way to do this under Windows is with cygwin, right?

Comment: No, there is a windows port: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you have any link for an example doing a recursive replacement please?

Comment: Unless you don't have `find` under Windows that's going to be tricky. I don't do windows scripting. If you have a Unix system around, use that and the commit. This can be done in a single line in Unix:
`find . -type f -name '*.java' -exec iconv -f iso88591 -t utf8 {} > {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

I use [iconv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html)  for that purpose

```
// Convert *.java files from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 file encoding in a folder and all subfolders
for x in `find . -name '*.java'` ; do iconv -f ISO-8859-2 -t UTF-8 $x > "$x.utf8"; rm $x; mv "$x.utf8" $x; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for convert only non UTF-8 files:

for f in $(find . -name "*.*")
do
filename="${f%.*}"
echo -n "$f"
#file -i $f
if file -i $f | grep -wq "iso-8859-1"
then
mkdir -p converted
cp $f ./converted
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 $f > "${filename}_utf8"
mv "${filename}_utf8" $f
echo ": CONVERTED TO UTF-8."
else
echo ": UTF-8 ALREADY."
fi
done